# How to use a microwave oven's grill mode

Tags: microwave

I am trying to use the grill mode in my microwave oven. I would like to know what type of utensil can be used in it? Steel/microwave safe etc

Comment: Do you have some sort of hybrid or combination oven?  What does the manual say?  (I know, crazy, but...)

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ It is a microwave oven with options for convection and grill modes

Comment: Does grill mode mean a conventional (non-microwave) heating mode?

Comment: jogabonito, we can likely skip a lot of these back and forth questions if you simply tell us the make and model of the microwave; hopefully there's a manual online. Your question is mostly equivalent to "does it use microwaves while in grill mode" - and we don't know for sure, since there are a lot of different microwaves out there.

Comment: @Jefromi My model is Sanyo EM-C7586V. I didnt find too much about the grill mode in the manual. I could look up if you want something specific. The input grill power is 1100W

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're lucky, the owner's manual is clear or there's a "microwave on/off" type button that you can use to make sure that no microwaves are used while in grill mode.

If in doubt, you have to assume that the microwave still uses microwaves when in convection or grill mode, since many definitely do. That means you need microwave safe dishes (generally, no metal).

Or else, you can test by simply boiling some water. Try in normal microwave mode, see how long it takes to boil, then try the same setup in grill mode. If it takes substantially longer (or you get bored before it starts boiling), it's probably not using microwaves, so you can use whatever heat-safe dishes you want in grill mode. If it boils just as fast, it's using microwaves, and you need microwave-safe dishes.

(I suppose if you're reckless/impatient, you could also test by putting some aluminum foil in, be ready to quickly stop it, and just seeing if it sparks/catches on fire...)

Comment: nice tip about the boiling water test

Answer (score 0):

Check the manual which comes along with the Microwave. If you have lost it search the manual for the model number. Most of the times 2 models with slight variation will have 2 different model numbers, but the working principle is same